# Google Sheets add-on not visible in Marketplace Apps for site-wide installation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, add-on, google-apps-marketplace

I have followed all the steps here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/domain-wide

And then went through them a million times already.
I can install and use it if I click Test Installation Flow from under Google Apps Marketplace SDK Configuration.

When publishing, the check box for Publish in Google Apps Marketplace is always checked.

Still, when I log in as a domain administrator and go to Marketplace Apps - Add App, I can't find my app in the list.

If you're from Google support, here's the link to my app, maybe you can check something in the backend: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/enabler4sheets/inpioilbljppoobbblcpbpjplkefmkep

Answer (score 1):

Based from the [Google Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/publish#prepare_and_deploy_your_add-on), The add-on’s name must be the same as the name of the Apps Script project. The checkbox next to Publish in Google Apps Marketplace should be checked only if you are publishing the [add-on for domain-wide install](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/domain-wide#while_publishing) and you are not bundling the add-on with an existing [Google Apps Marketplace app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/domain-wide#while_publishing_1). See the [style guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/style) for more information on the other fields. Select the most recent version of your code and click Create web store draft. This will open a new page for you to configure the add-on for inclusion in the Chrome Web Store.

What I can suggest is to repeat the process based from the document. Please check the `Complete application ad publish your add-on`: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/publish#complete_application_and_publish_your_add-on

Comment: My add-on name is the same everywhere: Apps Script project, dev console project, Google Apps Marketplace SDK. I double-checked everything, and I still can't get this to work. I do want to publish it for domain-wide install, and I don't have an app to bundle it with, but according to the documentation here (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/domain-wide#while_publishing) you can publish it like that. For some reason I don't have that luck. The worst thing is - there's no support for this, all Google Apps for Work support could do is send me to StackOverflow.